# xcode trouble passing 3 nsstring values between views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsview

Hello all I am having a lot of trouble passing values between views,

I have a StartViewController with 3 textboxes FirstName LastName Email I would like to pass the values of them to ViewController I have tried a few different things but nothing I do seems to work I have tried this:
http://highscoreapps.blogspot.com/2012/05/passing-data-between-view-controllers.html
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/

but I seem to not able to get anything to work. 
Here is some of my code so far:

in StartViewControler.h

```
@protocol DataPassingControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)passDataMethod:(NSString *)TextFirstName Data2:(NSString *)TextLastName Data3:(NSString *)TextEmail;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *uTextFirstName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *uTextLastName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *uTextEmail;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sTextFirstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sTextLastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sTextEmail; 

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<DataPassingControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

in StartViewController.M

```
-(IBAction)ButtonTakeSurvey:(id)sender{
self.sTextFirstName = uTextFirstName.text;
self.sTextLastName = uTextLastName.text;
self.sTextEmail = uTextEmail.text;

[self.delegate passDataMethod:sTextFirstName Data2:sTextLastName Data3:sTextEmail];

ViewController *myView1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:myView1.view];
}
```

in ViewController.H I have added
    #import "StartViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <DataPassingControllerDelegate>
```

how do I get the firstName LastName Email on the ViewController.m I would like it to populate 3 local variable that I have onload.

Thanks!

Comment: You establish addressability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a singleton class to handle communication between ViewControllers. the Singleton pattern lets you separate data from the controllers themselves. Below is a version of the code I use.

DataManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataManager : NSObject

+(DataManager*)sharedInstance;
-(void) setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id<NSCopying>)aKey;
-(id) objectForKey:(id)aKey;
-(void) removeAllObjects;
@end
```

DataManager.m

```
#import "DataManager.h"

@implementation DataManager

static DataManager *sharedInstance;
static NSMutableDictionary* dictionary;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
    return self;
}


+ (DataManager *) sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == NULL)
        {
            sharedInstance = [[DataManager alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}


-(void) setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id<NSCopying>)aKey
{
    [dictionary setObject:anObject forKey:aKey];
}

-(id) objectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    return [dictionary objectForKey:aKey];
}

-(void) removeAllObjects
{
    [dictionary removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

In order to use it all you have to do is in the first view controller, get the sharedInstance and set the values before pushing (or presenting, in the case of a modal VC) the ViewController.

```
DataManager* dm = [DataManager sharedInstance]
[dm removeAllObjects];
[dm setObject:firstNameString forKey:@"firstName"];
[dm setObject:lastNameString forKey:@"lastName"];
[dm setObject:emailString forKey:@"email"];
```

then in the ViewDidLoad (or viewWillAppear or whatever) of the second ViewController you can get the values from the singleton like:

```
DataManager* dm = [DataManager sharedInstance]
NSString* firstName = (NSString*)[dm objectForKey:@"firstName"];
NSString* lastName = (NSString*)[dm objectForKey:@"lastName"];
NSString* email = (NSString*)[dm objectForKey:@"email"];
//do stuff with the values.
```

If you want to read more about singletons (I'd recommend it if you're not currently familiar with the pattern) the wikipedia article is pretty excellent, and there are a number of OO design sites that discuss it in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating the data model from your controllers. There are many ways to do this, but a simple way would be to create a "user profile" class as a singleton (shared instance across the app) and store the data there. That way, each controller that needs that data, can access it themselves.

Comment: its a small app just 2 views I would like to just pass the values from one to the next and then it will sent to a webservice and never used again. And I have now idea what you are talking about lol.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like all you need to do is add `passDataMethod` to your ViewController.m:

```
-(void)passDataMethod:(NSString *)TextFirstName Data2:(NSString *)TextLastName Data3:(NSString *)TextEmail
{
    NSString *myLocalVar1 = [NSString stringWithString:TextFirstName];
    NSString *myLocalVar2 = [NSString stringWithString:TextLastName];
    NSString *myLocalVar3 = [NSString stringWithString:TextEmail];

    // Do something useful with myLocalVar1, 2, and 3 here
}
```

Comment: I have tried this:
`code`
    NSString *sFirst;
    NSString *sLast;
    NSString *sEmail;

    -(void)passDataMethod:(NSString *)TextFirstName Data2:(NSString *)TextLastName Data3:(NSString *)TextEmail {
    sFirst = [NSString stringWithString:TextFirstName];
    sLast = [NSString stringWithString:TextLastName];
    sEmail = [NSString stringWithString:TextEmail];
    }
`code`
But when I set breakpoints it does not ever hit them so I don't think its working.

Comment: This should be called when you hit `[self.delegate passDataMethod:sTextFirstName Data2:sTextLastName Data3:sTextEmail];` in your StartViewController.m.  Are you sure you're hitting that line in StartViewController.m?

Comment: Yes it is hitting it on startviewcontoller just not in viewController so viewcontroller the variables never get filled.

Comment: My guess then would be that you never set ViewController to be the delegate of StartViewController. I see that you already accepted another answer tho, and that is also a good way to send data between controllers, so I won't bother going into any more detail on how to do the data transfer with delegates, unless someone asks to see it.